# Can I use eval boards for SoCs that support dual-role USB for prototyping a USB3 peripheral?

Tags: usb, usb-device, prototyping, soc

I have recently started prototyping a custom USB peripheral that I would find very useful in my work if it existed. I made the extremely crude proof-of-concept version using an Arduino Due, its native USB port, the Arduino Ethernet shield, and some basic extra circuitry. The thing worked in principle, but both the port and the microcontroller on the Due are very slow, too slow for the device to actually be useful.

USB3/SuperSpeed would be far more practical for my purposes, but I mostly have a software development background, so that's kind of a daunting step up. Most recommendations I can find online for building USB 3 peripherals are for the Cypress FX3. I'm sure that's a great component, but connecting its super-general "GPIF" up to other controllers to fulfil my device's other I/O needs seems a little out of reach for my skill level.

I noticed the Raspberry Pi 4 has a dual-role USB port which can be used to make the RPi act as either a USB peripheral or host; as far as I can tell, in that case it's "only" High-Speed USB 2.0. Unlike the FX3, there's obviously plenty of other commodity I/O available (Ethernet, PCIe, …). This got me thinking about other SoCs with dual-role USB ports, surely there are some that support SuperSpeed?

So far, I have found:

- TI's **AM57x** series of controllers, which do appear to have a USB port which apparently supports operating in host, peripheral, and DRD modes *and* supports SuperSpeed. TI's own pre-made boards seem to only allow using the USB 3.0 port in host mode, but I found [a board from Compulab](https://www.compulab.com/products/sbcs/sbc-am57x-ti-am5728-am5718-single-board-computer/#evalkit) which wires it up to a Micro-B connector.
- The Allwinner **A80** which appears to support USB 3.0 OTG. Theobroma Systems [appears to have a dev kit for it](https://www.theobroma-systems.com/evaluationkit/haikou-q7-dev-kit/#) which has a USB 3.0 micro-B connector.
- NXP's **i.MX 8M** SoC and the [MCIMX8M-EVK](https://www.nxp.com/design/development-boards/i-mx-evaluation-and-development-boards/evaluation-kit-for-the-i-mx-8m-applications-processor:MCIMX8M-EVK) eval kit. The C-Type connector supposedly supports OTG. PCIe is provided in the form of the (awkward for SSDs) Key E M.2 slot. No SATA.

**Am I on the right track here?** Can I effectively design a USB peripheral with one of these? As in, implementing interrupt and bulk endpoints, responding to control requests, etc. all in software. As these are full-featured microprocessors, not just controllers, this presumably happens in a kernel module or directly on top of some RTOS?

It took a lot of searching to even find those 2 examples - is there a comparison of controllers/SoCs somewhere that might let me rapidly search for features such as dual-role or peripheral-mode USB 3.0?

My requirements:

- Acts as a USB SuperSpeed *peripheral*, with the characteristics and behaviour of the device implemented in firmware.

  - As a baseline, I'd like to implement USB Storage class Bulk-only-transport
  - Ideally, I'd like to be able to implement a composite device with more than one interface, each performing different tasks (storage, HID, etc.)
- Commodity I/O for networking (Ethernet, TCP/IP stack) and storage (SATA or PCIe/NVMe). The final peripheral should contain an SSD; whether that's SATA or NVMe doesn't make much of a difference at USB3 Gen1 speeds.
- Sufficient memory bandwidth and compute performance to feed the SuperSpeed USB interface. (realistically, any gigahertz class processor seems likely to fit the bill)

Comment: So, small problem: I was about to comment that product recommendation questions are off-topic here, based on your title, and on the "are there any..." question in there. However, you *do* have very valid technical questions that are *not* product recommendation questions! Could you maybe redact your question to not ask for boards to buy, but highlights your question about the things you've considered so far (as far as I can tell, that's really just deleting the second half of the title, and removing that one sentence that asks for other boards).

Comment: What does the peripheral you are making actually need to do? Process data? Interface with sensors? Implement networking? The things on the far side of the USB interface will define your hardware selection.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the comments - I've adjusted the title and contents of the question to hopefully be more in line with the rules.

Comment: The FX3 series software demos include doing MSC and HID over USB3, and there are USB storage optimized versions of those chips.  If that is all you're looking for, take a look at one of their dev kits.  They're cheap and have lots of examples.

Comment: @user1850479 as far as I can tell, the “storage optimised” version (FX3S) has a pair of SD interfaces. SD cards tend to be unreliable and often have bad wear levelling - I’d much rather use a SATA or PCIe SSD for backend storage. Aside from that, I can’t find the FX3S in stock anywhere, let alone an eval board for it…

Comment: @pmdj You mentioned host side SATA, did you mean device side? So you want a USB device with it hose features?

Comment: @user1850479 I want to be able to connect an SSD to the device's controller, so the device can submit storage I/O requests to the SSD. (There won't be a 1:1 pass-through mapping between the requests received via USB and those submitted to the backing store via SATA/NVMe, so a simple bridge chip probably won't be sufficient.) So I guess by "host side SATA" I mean that the USB peripheral's controller needs to contain some kind of SATA host controller or a PCIe root.

Comment: @user1850479 The TI AM5728 SoC on the first board does seem to have a SATA host interface, and that's also exposed on the Compulab eval board I linked to. The SoC also has 2 lanes of PCIe, although the eval board exposes these as 2 PCIe Mini card slots; a single M.2 or standard PCIe slot with 2 lanes would be more convenient for an SSD.

Comment: @user1850479 The Allwinner A80 "HAIKOU-Q7" eval board I linked to has a PCIe x4 slot so that should work ok for adding an NVMe SSD. No SATA on that one it seems.

Comment: @user1850479 My question boils down to: to what extent can I program such a SoC to behave like an arbitrary USB peripheral? Does dual-role USB mean that in peripheral mode I can freely choose how many USB interfaces there will be, what endpoints they consist of, customise all the descriptors, and handle all the incoming requests in software/firmware?

Comment: @user1850479 If not, what should I be looking at instead? Or either way, is there generally a "lighter" solution?

Comment: For USB, host refers to the PC, device the thing you're using, so my suggestion of an fx3 (perfect if you want host side storage) won't work. You're going to need something with PCIe, Ata and USB stacks, so Linux or Windows. A Pi is a good choice, I would look and see if the USB3 models are fast enough for you. Avoid any obscure devices unless you're planning to spend months or years writing your own USB stack with the features you need.

Comment: USB devices implementing multiple roles is fairly common. Just needs software support in whatever OS and drivers you're running.

Comment: @user1850479 As I mentioned in the question, I did consider the RPi4. But this only supports High-Speed (USB 2.0) on its dual-role port, so I can’t build a SuperSpeed peripheral with it.